# Using FuelSDK-PHP to connect Drupal 8 to Exact Target, and the "Email Address" attribute doesn't seem to be available to map to

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, fuel-sdk, attribute

Using FuelSDK-PHP to connect Drupal 8 to ExactTarget Marketing Cloud.  The library pulls ALL of the subscriber attributes EXCEPT "Email Address".  Currently using ET_ProfileAttribute::get() to pull them.

Is there anything on the ExactTarget end of things that would allow all subscriber attributes EXCEPT for "Email Address" to be available?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried 'EmailAddress' with no space?

Comment: The issue is not typing in the field name.  This library makes a call to ExactTarget for all attribute fields.  When pulling all attribute names to populate a dropdown all attributes are available except for "Email Address" (or any similar named field).